# USB host support for STM32

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-host

Is it possible (is any IC) that make USB host with STM32? I mean for example UART->USB or SPI->USB converter that make USB host. It sounds strange, I know. Microcontrollers like STM32F103 make USB but only in device mode. I need host mode for making USB communication line transmitter-transceiver, where transceiver will be checking "USB frames". This solution is for analyze influence of noise to USB.

Comment: What is the real issue? CM noise between tower and external SMPS target?  Fix that instead!

Comment: In this case noise isn't a problem but subject of diploma thesis :)

Comment: Yes, there are STM32 micros which can act as a USB host. Some have more than one USB port, so they can be host & device at the same time - host on one port and device on the other. Go to ST's web site and look in their parametric search and you'll find them. 'Shopping' for parts is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

If you need USB host capabilities, than look for MCUs which support USB_OTG_HS or USB_OTG_FS - those support both device and host functions and can switch between them even On The Go according to your SW.
There are many STM32s that support these functions. I would recommend using one of the STM32 MCU selector or CubeMX tools for looking up parts that support these features.